# Reset the settings for footnote?

Tags: footnotes

I'm currently using the template of Applied Probability Trust to write a paper. In the `.cls` file of the template, it appears that the setting of `footnote` is modified in such a way that the information of postal addresses of the authors appears in the footnote of the title page. However, it also somehow cancels the automatic numbering of the footnotes in the main body of the paper.

The problem I'm encountering now is that it *seems* to forbid two footnotes on one page (otherwise, the compilation does not go through). With only one footnote on a page, the `footnotetext` appears at the bottom of the page but there is no `footnotemark`.

My question is how I change the settings properly so that I can get the default setting of the footnote back, i.e. automatic numbering etc.? The clause that seems to modify the behaviour of the footnote in the `.cls` file is as follows.

```
\renewcommand\thefootnote{}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\flushleft\raisebox{2pt}{\rule{42.68pt}{0.4pt}}}
\skip\footins=17.07pt
```

The link to the the `.cls` file is [here](http://www.appliedprobability.org/data/files/Submittal%20Guidelines/aptpub.cls) and the template file is [here](http://www.appliedprobability.org/data/files/Submittal%20Guidelines/template.tex).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the class *really* have that definition of `\footnoterule`? It's really one of the worst I've seen.

Comment: @egreg Yes. I took it from the `.cls` file.

Comment: If the class is written that way, I can imagine you have nightmares using it! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the lines

```
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}
```

to your preamble or wherever you want to start with them.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{aptpub}

\renewcommand\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill} % just to see the output

Text\footnote{A first footnote}

Text\footnote{A second footnote}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

Looking at your template you may also need the line

```
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
```

before that one.

Comment: Thanks! But this would mess up with the intended effects of the affiliations on the title page. Can this be done after the title page?

Comment: @WilliamZhang Of course. Put that line after your titlepage.

Comment: Works like a charm! One more question, though, how can I reset the counter? The first footnote is not numbered as 1, since the authors already took the first few footnotes.

Comment: @WilliamZhang See the edit